# How to encrypt stored procedures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to encrypt stored procedures in MySQL. Since I was doing the database work on Oracle and all of my stored procedures are encrypted, I needed to migrate from Oracle to MySQL so as this problem came.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **dont** think there is a way to encrypt stored procedure in MYSQL. I would recommend you to change the priviledge for the users for which, whom you dont want that they should access your stored procedure.

You can see this bug reported in MYSQL: [Bug #4210  Stored Procedure Encryption](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4210) and also [Bug #19516    stored procedur encoding/obfuscating](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19516)

Comment: @Drew:- Yes that is a workaround but OP has asked for encryption, which I dont think is possible.

Comment: I don't see the possibility either

Comment: @Drew:- Yes there is none thats why I have linked the related bugs from MySQL.

Comment: @AnayaUpadhyay:- You have to decrypt your stored procedure at the Oracle database itself. You cannot do it on the MySQL.

Comment: yeah, i did that @RahulTripathi
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot encrypt stored procedures in a really useful way, because MySQL server will have to decrypt it anyway when it reads stored procedure from it's tables.

You can protect your Stored Procedure Code as like this in SQL Server.This is not for MySql but this is for SQL Server.

[How Do I Protect My Stored Procedure Code?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38583/How-Do-I-Protect-My-Stored-Procedure-Code)